# CSS Overflow incorrect in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem with IE7, i just noticed couple days ago that my floated divs are overfloating all the way out of the box to the left

here is the problem:
http://www.locksmith-service-rockville-md.com/door-knob-lever-set

i have been trying to figure it out for the past 3 days, so far with out any success,

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do me a favour and stop changing the live site when I'm trying to debug it?

Comment: it's funny it works on 11/15 sites, which have the exact same css

Comment: sounds good :) right now it's the way it was in the beginning, do you have any recommendations for good debugging tools for ie7?

Comment: Good, I'll look again. I'm using IE's Developer Tools; you should be able to bring that up by pressing F12.

Comment: Thank you, i am going to try to look at it my self also, but it's not going so good for me so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kept changing the live site, so I'm slightly confused.

- Make sure `#left-side` **does not** have `overflow: auto`.
- On `div .views-row-odd, div .views-row-even`, remove `clear: right`.
  *(this change doesn't seem to be required, but I also don't see the need for `clear: right` here)*
- From your HTML source code, remove `<div class="space"></div>`.
  That's not the way to get the space at the top; it's *causing problems*.

Do those changes to your live site, and let me know what you think.

If that's good so far in the different browsers you're testing in, we can see about adding back in that spacing, using a different method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try:

```
div#left-side
{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This fixes 90% of all floating issues.

Comment: overflow:auto even creates something more bizzar

it just create a scroll box around the item, and it keeps on floating everything to the left and outside of the container

Comment: Really? It looks the same to me (Google Chrome 10.0 Dev). Did you apply it to `#left-side`? I changed my answer a few times within the past minute...

Comment: In Chrome it seems to be alright, the overflow auto messes things up a little in the top box.

i have tried to apply the overflow auto to the .view-content

Comment: Overflow auto on the left-side div adds scrolls, but the images still going under

Answer (score 0):

When eliminated float: left on first div with class "views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first", more specifically ".views-row-odd" seem fixed your problem.

Comment: didn't work for me, i was thinking to try to clear left on the odd boxes, but it didn't work either. just messed things up in other browsers